# Why does this simple SwiftUI view modifier with transition produce a crash?

Tags: swiftui

I wrote this very simple `.modal` `View` modifier in SwiftUI.

When it is opened, I press `close` and before the transition finished `open` again, I get the following crash:

```
 Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before next touch
```

Sample code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Open") {
                withAnimation {
                    self.show.toggle()
                }
            }.disabled(self.show) // doesn't help
        }.modal(isShowing: self.$show) {
            Button("Close") {
                withAnimation {
                    self.show.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func modal<C>(isShowing: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> C) -> some View where C: View {
        self.modifier(ModalView(isShowing: isShowing, content: content))
    }
}

struct ModalView<C>: ViewModifier where C: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    let content: () -> C
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content.zIndex(0)
            if self.isShowing {
                self.content()
                    .background(Color.primary.colorInvert())
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .zIndex(1)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Can someone explain how I can prevent this? It seems that the `Bool` responsible for toggling is set before the animation has finished. Is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to disable below content (as you introduce modality) but in a bit different place

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
struct ModalView<C>: ViewModifier where C: View {
    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    let content: () -> C

    @State private var interactive: Bool   // track state

    init(isShowing: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> C) {
        self._isShowing = isShowing
        self._interactive = State(initialValue: !isShowing.wrappedValue)
        self.content = content
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content.zIndex(0).disabled(!interactive)   // disable here !!
            if self.isShowing {
                self.content()
                    .background(Color.primary.colorInvert())
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                    .zIndex(1)
                    .onAppear { self.interactive = false }     // << !!
                    .onDisappear { self.interactive = true }   // << !!
            }
        }
    }
}
```